# datatable plugin php and json errror

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, html

i am new to programming.i try to design a admin panel that can directly edit the users data with the help of datatable plugin.this there is some error with JSON format

this is my index page

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Live Add Edit Delete Datatables Records using PHP Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <style>
  body
  {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  .box
  {
   width:1270px;
   padding:20px;
   background-color:#fff;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius:5px;
   margin-top:25px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container box">
   <h1 align="center">Live Add Edit Delete Datatables Records using PHP Ajax</h1>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <br />
    <div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="alert_message"></div>
    <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Staff id</th>
       <th>Password</th>
       <th>Email_id</th>
       <th>gender</th>
       <th>qualification</th>
       <th>course1</th>
       <th>course2</th>
       <th>course3</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){

  fetch_data();

  function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"fetch.php",
     type:"POST"
    }
   });
  }

  function update_data(id, column_name, value)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"update.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{id:id, column_name:column_name, value:value},
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
     $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
     fetch_data();
    }
   });
   setInterval(function(){
    $('#alert_message').html('');
   }, 5000);
  }

  $(document).on('blur', '.update', function(){
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   var column_name = $(this).data("column");
   var value = $(this).text();
   update_data(id, column_name, value);
  });

  $('#add').click(function(){
   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Insert</button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
   var first_name = $('#data1').text();
   var last_name = $('#data2').text();
   var password = $('#data3').text();
   if(first_name != '' && last_name != '' && password != '')
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"insert.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name, password:password},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Both Fields is required");
   }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this?"))
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"delete.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{id:id},
     success:function(data){
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

This is my fetch.php file

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "flash");
$columns = array('staff_id', 'password','email_id','gender','qualification','course1','course2','course3');

$query = "SELECT * FROM staff ";

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $query .= '
 WHERE staff_id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR email_id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' 
 ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
} 

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);

$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["SINO"].'" data-column="staff_id">' . $row["staff_id"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["SINO"].'" data-column="password">' . $row["password"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["SINO"].'" data-column="email_id">' . $row["email_id"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["SINO"].'" data-column="gender">' . $row["gender"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["SINO"].'" data-column="qualification">' . $row["qualification"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["SINO"].'" data-column="course1">' . $row["course1"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["SINO"].'" data-column="course2">' . $row["course2"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["SINO"].'" data-column="course3">' . $row["course3"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row["SINO"].'">Delete</button>';
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function get_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM staff";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

this shows an alert  message like

> DataTables warning: table id=user_data - Invalid JSON response. For
>   more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

the fetch.php file shows a error statement like

> Notice: Undefined index: length in C:\xampp\htdocs\FLASH\admin
>   modify\fetch.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: start in C:\xampp\htdocs\FLASH\admin
>   modify\fetch.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined index: length in C:\xampp\htdocs\FLASH\admin
>   modify\fetch.php on line 30
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\FLASH\admin modify\fetch.php on line
>   33
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\FLASH\admin modify\fetch.php on line
>   39
>
> Notice: Undefined index: draw in C:\xampp\htdocs\FLASH\admin
>   modify\fetch.php on line 62
>   {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":4,"recordsFiltered":null,"data":[]}

guy please help me to solve this issue please.

Comment: You've some mistake with your query, that's why you've seeing this warning on line 33. Your JSON data is failing because of error messages that makes it invalid. Fix the errors and set `error_reporting ( E_NONE);` to avoid error output.

Comment: Where did you get the errors from `fetch.php` ? Just regular get query ? Use developer tools in your browser to see actual responce, because the errors leads to not filled post data. There is probably some error/warning in `fetch.php` which is shown in top of responce and cause the `Invalid JSON response`, you should look for actual responce in developer tools to see what exactly is the problem here.

Comment: thank u guys i solve my problem with your help